# Multiple If condition inside classic HTML Email template

Tags: formula, email-template, formula-field

In classic email template I am trying to put multiple if condition for two different fields and that  two fields are formula fields
The fields names are

- X1Annual_Meeting__c
- X1Proxy_Other__c

if X1Annual_Meeting__c=0 and X1Proxy_Other__c =0 then I have to display "Meeting and proxy are false"

if I put multiple if condition as below then I am not getting anything

```
{!IF(Opportunity.X1Annual_Meeting__c = True, "Outer Green" , IF(Opportunity.X1Proxy_Other__c = True, "Inside Green" , "Meeting and proxy are false"))}
```

but if I put single If like below then I am getting "Meeting alone false"

```
{!IF(Opportunity.X1Annual_Meeting__c = True, "Outer Green" , "Meeting alone false"}
```

but I need to make two IF for different fields
I tried with different options with 0 , true, false nothing is working

Comment: Some how managed to resolve this issue. Thanks